# With JQuery trying to send multiple value from html input form and get back result

Tags: jquery

With JQuery trying to send multiple value from html input form to another php file and get back result

This is html form

```
<form id="form1" >

<input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount1" value="1">
<input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount2" value="2">
<input type="text" name="your_form[]" id="amount3" value="3">
</form>
```

This is JQuery

```
 $.post("__02.php", $("#form1").serialize(),
 function(data){
 $('#currency_load').html(data);
 }
 );
```

This is php `__02.php`

```
print_r($_REQUEST['your_form']);
echo '<br>test';
```

And here expect to see content of `print_r($_REQUEST['your_form']);`

```
<div id="currency_load"></div>
```

But see only `echo '<br>test';`

Can not understand what is incorrect. Please advice.

From my opinion something is incorrect here `$("#form1").serialize()`, but what? As if simple situation, but can not understand

Ups, added `$(document).ready(function() {` Now ok... OH, now understand. In file jquery was above html and started before html, so no values in `form1`

Comment: `$_POST['your_form']`

Comment: Used `print_r($_POST['your_form']);`. See the same word `test`. Expect to see array with values `1,2,3`.

Comment: Install firebug or something similar, to examine ajax requests.

Comment: Have not used firebug before. Now installed. `F12` and...what to do next, please?

Comment: Ummm, I'm not familiar with PHP but try changing name attribute for inputs to amount1, amount2 and amount3 and in php do print_r($_REQUEST['amount1']); print_r($_REQUEST['amount2']); print_r($_REQUEST['amount3']);

Comment: The same result. See `test` and do not see input values

Comment: Aha, try echo $_REQUEST['amount1'] ?

Comment: Finally understood where was problem. Wrote in answer. Thanks to all